# Should AI generated questions and or answers be banned?

Tags: discussion, policy

[Relevant discussion that inspired this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26260/do-we-want-a-banner-warning-about-our-policy-on-ai-generated-content)

Questions and answers (content) generated by AIs like LLMs (e.g ChatGPT, Google Bard, character.ai) are not prohibited on the StackExchange network by default:

> With due consideration, we've decided no network-wide, general policy regarding banning ChatGPT, or other AI generated content, is necessary or helpful at this time.

~ [Slate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1037447/slate), a Community Manager, [in response to a question on whether AI content should be banned network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/391137).

Therefore, it's up to per-site metas to establish AI content policies.

However, unattributed AI content is *not* allowed on any StackExchange site, as it's considered plagiarism:

> However... [we] consider AI generated content to be "the work of others" and the requirements for referencing must be followed for all such content on the network.

(from the same answer by slate)

That is to say, AI generated content not marked as such is not allowed by default. No questions about that.

So,

**Should properly referenced AI generated content be allowed on the Code Golf StackExchange?**

Comment: I don't think it should be allowed, but just for fun I tried using it and it golfed `print("".join(list("Hello, World!")))` (outputs Hello, World!) into `print(*"Hello, World!")` which doesn't even output the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

As many have pointed out, it's practically impossible to get any of the current statistical models to produce a valid well golfed CGSE answer. We could speculate as to why that is, but it is evident.

So currently there is no issue. Answers from LLMs are de-facto banned on the account that they don't follow other rules.

I don't see any sense in attempting to fix something that isn't a problem. Instead of trying to speculate about what the future might hold and what effective policy would be, we should revisit issue if statistical models ever become proficient enough to get past these first hurdles.

Comment: This covers answers. AI-generated questions, when tweaked, could be valid.